# how to transmit serial data from GPS device to computer through IP?

Tags: gps, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

Well..I have found some third party application regarding sending data from com port to IP. but I have not found any basic tutorial regarding them. so can anyone help me with this? I have a GPS device which I will connect to my laptop through usb to serial adapter.Now I need to send that data from a laptop to another laptop on same network. Can I use putty to view that data in another laptop(receiver)? Is virtual serial port driver meant for this kind of application?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write your own tool for it, you can simply use [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/) and set up a daemon that reads piped data from one process and broadcasts it to all connected clients.

If you want something that reads the data from the serial port and then transmits it to clients, you'll need to write a server application that accepts connections and sends data around, but there's entire books on this. It should be easy to do for your purposes as written here, but it depends on the amount of control you need.

Alternatively you can use a virtual serial port application as you had mentioned, which might be the easiest route. The two devices will need to be on the same network unless the application supports TCP based virtualization instead of the common Ethernet based implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This Python script works very well as a free "device server". Just enter the serial port configuration and the IP address and port information.

https://github.com/jaredly/pydbgp/blob/master/symbian/serial_tcp_redirect.py

This can work on both Windows and Linux.

You need pyserial.

You can always try using stand alone hardware such as the SENA LS100 device server.